# Convert current animated banner into a nivo slider from bespoke CMS

Tags: php, content-management-system, nivo-slider

I've taken over a website that currently has a custom built CMS which we want to keep. The one change we want to make is to the homepage animated banner as it's pretty poor.

It's currently setup so it grabs the images input through the cms and outputs them in an animated banner. I want to keep that functionality but feed the images into a nivo slider instead. I'm a little cautious as to how I go about doing it.

This is the code that's outputting the images into the animated banner (I think!!):

```
<? if ($page[id] == 1) { ?>
<?
    $i = 0;
    $homebanners = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banners ORDER BY banner_order ASC");
    while ($banner = mysql_fetch_assoc($homebanners)) {
        if (!$first) { $first = true; $bannerimage = $banner[banner_image]; $bannertext = $banner[banner_text]; $bannerlink = $banner[banner_link]; }

        $javascript .= "bannerimage[$i] = '$banner[banner_image]';
        bannertext[$i] = '".addslashes($banner[banner_text])."';
        bannerlink[$i] = '$banner[banner_link]';
        ";
        $i++;
    }

if ($i > 1) {
?>
<script>

    var curbanner = 0;

    var bannerimage = new Array();
    var bannertext = new Array();
    var bannerlink = new Array();

    <? echo $javascript; ?>

    totalbanners = bannerimage.length;

    function changebanner() {
        curbanner = curbanner + 1;
        if (totalbanners == curbanner) { curbanner = 0; }

        bannerurl = 'banner_images/'+bannerimage[curbanner];

          $('#bannertext').fadeOut('100', function() {
            $("#banner").animate({"height": "0px"}, 350, "linear", 
            function() { 
                $('#banner').css({ 'background-image': 'url('+bannerurl+')' }).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#banner").animate({"height": "222px"}, 350, "linear", 
                function() {
                    document.getElementById('btext').innerHTML=bannertext[curbanner];
                    document.getElementById('bannerlink').href=bannerlink[curbanner];
                    if (bannerlink[curbanner] == "") { document.getElementById('bannerlink').innerHTML = ''; } else {  document.getElementById('bannerlink').innerHTML = 'Read more...'; }
                    $('#bannertext').fadeIn('100');
                });
            });
          });
    }

    setInterval('changebanner()',10000);
</script><? } ?>
```

And...

```
<div id="rightcol" style="height:222px;">
    <div id="banner" style="background-image:url('banner_images/<? echo $bannerimage; ?>')">
        <div id="bannertext">
            <h2 id="btext"><? echo $bannertext; ?></h2>
            <a id="bannerlink" href="<? echo $bannerlink; ?>" class="readmore"><? if ($bannerlink) { ?>Read more...<? } ?></a>
        </div><!-- END bannertext -->
    </div><!-- END banner -->
</div><!-- END rightcol -->
```

How can I get the image, banner text and banner link into a nivo slider in this format:

```
<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
    <a href="page-link-1"><img src="image-1.jpg" alt="" title="banner-text-1" /></a>
    <a href="page-link-2"><img src="image-2.jpg" alt="" title="banner-text-2" /></a>
    <a href="page-link-3"><img src="image-3.jpg" alt="" title="banner-text-3" /></a>
</div>
```

The amount of slides inputted through the cms should be infinite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
if ($page[id] == 1) {

    $i = 0;
    $html = '';

    $homebanners = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM banners ORDER BY banner_order ASC");
    while ($banner = mysql_fetch_assoc($homebanners)) {
        if (!$first) { $first = true; $bannerimage = $banner[banner_image]; $bannertext = $banner[banner_text]; $bannerlink = $banner[banner_link]; }

        $html .= "<a href=\"$bannerlink\"><img src=\"$bannerimage\" alt=\"$bannertext\" title=\"$bannertext\" /></a>";
        $i++;
    }

    if ($i > 1) {
        echo "<div id=\"slider\" class=\"nivoSlider\">";
        echo $html;
        echo "</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Cheers, I'm getting this error back though - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/dtrmedic/public_html/index.php on line 47 (being this line) - $html .= "<a href="$bannerlink"><img src="$bannerimage" alt="$bannertext" title="$bannertext" /></a>";

Comment: I've also found a bit of extra code that was outputting the banner, I'll update the question

Comment: fixed - missed escape characters

Comment: Thanks. It doesn't seem to cycle through all the images etc. It's just showing the first one it keeps loading that one over and over.